# Find script not completing correctly

Tags: bash

I've been tasked with creating a bash script to implement on our company's Asterisk servers which should do the following:

- Search through the `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/` dir and its sub directories.
- Find files of type .wav and .mp3 and remove these if their time stamp exceeds 60 days
- Remove any empty directories thereafter the files have been removed.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e

ASTDIR=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/; #VAR to point to asterisk dir

find ${ASTDIR}. -type f -name '*.wav' -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;#remove wav > 60 days

find ${ASTDIR}. -type f -name '*.mp3' -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;#remove mp3 > 60 days

find ${ASTDIR} -type d -empty -delete ; # Delete any empty directories

exit;
```

The problems I'm experiencing with this however, are plenty. I feel like my logic is solid but the script just doesn't seem to generate the output I would like/expecting.

The amount of files is quite large so its understandable that find would sometimes take a long time to run.

I've ran the command a few times with debugging on, with output like the following:

`+ find /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/. -type f -name '*.wav' -mtime +60 -exec rm '{}' ';'`

It executes and perpetually hangs as far as I can see, I decided impatience may be an issue so I decided to let it sit, I came back later to see that it had supposedly finished running however the mp3 files which were older than 60 days hadn't been removed, leading me to believe that the find command did not actually run.

I then swapped the find wav command with find mp3 which took a while to run, and did not delete everything.

I am so confused to what I may be doing wrong?

With both find --> rm commands not working, I commented them out to attempt the final find command which would delete empty directories

EVEN THIS did not delete all empty directories. I ran my script in one window and ran `watch -n1 ls -l | head -n20` in a window opposite it, clearly some empty dirs got deleted, but not all of them. I confirmed this because I knew which directories should get deleted but the command still left some empty directories behind!

Cherry on top, please shed some light on my dilemma!

This is CentOS server.

**UPDATE**

Editing the script to look as follows, solved my problems for me:

#!/bin/bash
set -e

```
cd /var/spool/asterisk/monitor

    find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -mtime +60 -delete  

    find . -type f -name '*.wav' -mtime +60 -delete

    find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: 1) You can see what `find` is trying to do using `-print`: `find ${ASTDIR}. -type f -name '*.wav' -mtime +60 -print -exec rm {} \;` 2) any reason you are not using `-delete` in the first two queries instead of dropping down to `-exec rm {} \;`? 3) About your non-disappearing "empty" directories, are you sure they are empty? `ls -al path/to/dir` to see if they have any hidden files (starting with a dot).

Comment: @Amadan I will add -print to the find commands and change out rm for delete. The reason for not using this was I feared it may be less safe, I'm guessing that is not the case?

Comment: Less safe in what way? `-delete` clearly says what it'll do to anything `find` finds. If anything, `-exec` is less safe if someone slipped you an alias or changed the path so `rm` is something else from what you thought. Also, since `-exec` launches an external program as a new process, many times over, I'd expect `-delete` to be faster. In either case, if you're worried about what you're trying to delete, first run the command with `-print`, then repeat with `-delete` when satisfied, till you know you're doing it right.

Comment: Also check permissions on both files and directories; if you don't have write access on files and `rwx` access on directories, deletion of files will likely fail (similar for directory removal).

Comment: I have ran the following command outside of a script to simply `ls` the files it finds. It is running but not printing any output at the moment. Will leave it to run for a little while and update. Command is: `find . -type f -name '*.wav' -mtime +60 -print -exec ls {} \;` This command is running within the monitor dir

Comment: You might want `ls -l` to show you the permissions, while you're at it. As it is, `-exec ls {} \;` will just do pretty much the same thing as `-print` will.

Comment: Alright will do so, this is ran from root user so I'm sure the permissions should not be a problem?

Comment: If so, yes, permissions should be a non-issue.

Comment: Replacing the `exec` commands with `-delete` would look like this, correct?
 `find ${ASTDIR}. -type f -name '*.mp3' -mtime +60 -delete;`

I am unsure of when exactly the semi-colon becomes necessary with find

Comment: The escaped semicolon is the part of the `-exec ...... \;` construct, to signal where the command being executed ends (as you can have more options afterwards). For example, `find . -name "*.foo" -exec echo "Moving {} to a safe place" \; -exec scp {} safeplace: \; -delete -exec echo Done \;`

Comment: So in this instance the semi-colon becomes redundant when using `-delete`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is only needed with `-exec`, `-execdir`, `-ok` and `-okdir` (which `man find` tells you about explicitly, when discussing those actions). It is actually more than redundant - `find . -name "*.foo" -delete \;` is a syntax error. The non-quoted (or escaped) semicolon just separates the `find` command (or any shell command) from the next command: `find . -name "*.foo" -print; echo Done` would first list all foo files, then output "Done", as a matter of two different shell commands (`find`, then `echo`).

Comment: @Amadan just to clarify, is it good practice to include an "exit;" at the end of my script?

Comment: I wouldn’t. But it’s usually harmless enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching in `${ASTDIR}.` (note the appended dot) which probably doesn't exist. Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
astdir=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/
find "$astdir" -type f -iname '*.wav' -mtime +60 -delete
find "$astdir" -type f -iname '*.mp3' -mtime +60 -delete
find "$astdir" -type d -empty -delete
```

You should always quote variables in case there are spaces in them, there's no need for semicolons at the end of the lines, `find` has a built-in capability to delete files, and you don't need to `exit` from a script. I also used the `iname` expression to ensure a case insensitive search; my Asterisk installation creates `*.WAV` files.

---

You can do boolean statements with find as well using `-or` and `-and` but it requires grouping with parentheses that need to be escaped so probably just easier to run multiple commands:

```
find "$astdir" \( -type f \( -iname '*.mp3' -or -iname '*.wav' \) -mtime +60 \) -or \( -type d -empty \)
```